# Padding in android, untidy my layout

Tags: android, layout

I have this layout inside a linerar layout (It is a custom Dialog), and when i add padding in the buttons, my layout become untidy.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/toggleGroupEntrega"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButtonEntregaOK"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/bgOff"
            android:checked="false"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/entrega_ok"
            android:textOff="@string/entrega_ok"
            android:textOn="@string/entrega_ok" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButtonEntregaRecusa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/bgOff"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/entrega_recusa"
            android:textOff="@string/entrega_recusa"
            android:textOn="@string/entrega_recusa" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/toggleButtonEntregaAvaria"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bgOff"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/entrega_avaria"
            android:textOff="@string/entrega_avaria"
            android:textOn="@string/entrega_avaria" />
  </RadioGroup>
```

that are the result:
[image]

if i remove **android:paddingLeft="5dp"** and **android:paddingRight="5dp"**, works well, but i really wanna a padding inside the elements(I do not want the text along the edges).

Why it happens? (have alot of free space if you see compelte image)
[image]

i wanna that way, but with a lite bit more padding (in this case, have only 2dp):
[image]

Comment: Try using proper casing. Or a smaller font size.

Comment: with lower, padding its works well too, but i wanna know, whyt it happens...

Comment: Have you added margin for the last togglebutton intentionally ? how do you want the layout to look like ?

Comment: Because the text goes to the next line, due to limited space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here is not `padding`, the issue here is that when you adding it last `ToggleButton` doesn't fit first line, and when it goest to the next one this happens. So as  `Der Golem` said :

> Try using proper casing. Or a smaller font size

The other thing, you can add

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

to your last item, that way you can undestand what causes the issue in your case

**EDIT :**  with following layout you can't reach your goal(unfortunetly)

Comment: with android:singleLine="true" and android:ellipsize="end", its works, tks :}